# Gaussian kernel's parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, machine-learning, variance

I learned from machine [learning course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/) that larger $\sigma^2$, leads to higher bias.

[image]

In this [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4264614/#b10-cin-suppl.1-2014-145) also mentioned larger bandwidth cause uniform kernel matrix. Which leads to high bias.

Then this [note](https://www.sec.in.tum.de/assets/lehre/ws0910/ml/slideslecture8.pdf) shows:
[image]
[image]

Based on my understanding: the picture on the left is more bias which means larger $\sigma^2$, but it has smaller $\gamma = \sigma^2$. This is first contradiction I encountered.

Then I tried to think what happen when $\sigma^2$ get larger. As $\sigma^2$ approaches $\infty$ then $exp(\frac{-\|u-v\|^2}{\sigma^2})$ approaches $\infty$, if we consider $\|u-v\|^2$ is positive constant. While the [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4264614/#b10-cin-suppl.1-2014-145) I mentioned earlier wrote

> a large σ value will cause the kernel matrix to be a uniform matrix with only entries 1.

This is the second contradiction I cannot understand. Why the kernel entries are 1?

How should I analyze the bias in this model? Could anyone help please to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As $\sigma$ goes to infinity the exp goes to 1 sand becomes relatively flat

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I plotted the function and I assumed as $\sigma$ reaches $+\infty$  the function approaches $+\infty$. I don't see why it reaches 1. Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: How could it go to infinity? The exponent is always non- positive. Therefor the exp is at most one. When sigma goes to infinity the exponent goes down to zero.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was confused.